# Angular 2 (click) and jQuery .clone() method not working

Tags: jquery, angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives

So i have a template for Angular 2 and this template uses jQuery components that "works". Well.. When the page is resized this fire a jQuery function that re-design the sidebar adding all the items of the top navbar using the "clone()" method of jQuery. Something like this:

```
... code ommited ...
 $navbar = $('nav').find('.navbar-collapse').first().clone(true);
... more code ommited...
```

This works well, this clone all the items of the navbar on the sidebar. The only problem is a button that i have on the sidebar to logout the system. This is the code:

```
<a class="text-danger link-pointer" (click)="doLogout()">
    <i class="pe-7s-power"></i> Cerrar Sesión
</a>
```

As you can see, i use the (click) binding that call a method of my class.
The problem is: **When the jQuery clone occours then is cloned, but without the binding**. So the link is broken. I can't use the [routerlink] binding because i need execute some code before redirect the user to the logout page.

Any idea to do this?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: component ts code?? why u r using jquery

Comment: The template it comes with this code. I cannot re-write all this in a component

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: The problem is that the method "doLogout" is never called because jquery clone() not copy the (click)= ... Part

Comment: for that you need to expose the relavant code and only 3 lines of markup will not be enough

Comment: `jquery clone` copies only jquery events it won't work with angular event bindings